# How typecasting work in Type Script

Tags: typescript

I am trying to find how **Type casting** work in Typescript. I tried with below code which is not working. Could please any help what I am missing.

```
// Code goes here

class DemoA { // A class declaration.

  // Implicitly null parametrized void type functions are declared.
  show1() {
    document.write("showA() function in class A");
  }
  show2() {
    document.write("after implicit/explicit casting this function cannot be called!");
  }
}
class DemoB { // Another class declaration.
  showB() {}
}

// An object creation of DemoA class type.
var objA: DemoA = new DemoA();

/* A function of class DemoA is being called through an object reference. NOTE: this function is being called before implicitly/explicitly cast occurs. */
objA.show1();

/* An object creation of DemoB class type. NOTE: this object is being created as “any” type. */
var objB: any = new DemoB;

/* An explicit cast from 'any' DemoB object type to 'DemoA' object type. NOTE: here a < > syntax is being used which indicates an explicit casting. */
objA = < DemoA > objB;

/* Another function of class DemoA is being trying to called through an object reference. NOTE: this function is being called after implicitly/explicitly cast has occurred. This function will not be called/invoked. */
objA.show2();
```

Comment: You need to give us the error messages you are seeing.  First of all, `DemoB.show2` does not exist, so you can't call it.  What happens when you change `DemoB.showB` to `DemoB.show2`?

Comment: objA.show2() is not a function

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh : Then how form control are casted to form array in Angular??

Comment: This will not work. You're _casting_ an object to a different type, but expecting a _conversion_. Not sure what you're trying to do and why, but there's no way to make this work. `show2()` will never be called on a `DemoB` instance. You might be fooling the compiler into thinking `objA` is of type `DemoA`, but in isn't in practice, and there's nothing TypeScript can do about it.